# Linq comparing DataTable with List<String>

Tags: linq, data-structures

I have a string list (List) that contains delimited fields.  An example would be:

```
List[0] = "7/1/2013,ABC,123456"
List[1] = "7/2/2013,DEF,234567"
```

I also have a DataTable where a record either will or will not contain the the values from the 2nd and 3rd column in the String List:

Example

```
Row[0][0]="ABC"   <-----String
Row[0][1]=123456  <-----Int32
```

What I want to do is find any records (via Linq) in the DataTable that DO NOT have corresponding values in the String List.

I've been googling for a while, and can't quite find the right way to do this with Linq...can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code snippet should give you an enumeration of the indices that do not have the appropriate DataTable values:

```
var correspondingRecords =
  from index in Enumerable.Range(0, List.Count)
  let items = List[index].Split(',')
  where !(item[1] == Row[index][0] && item[2] == Row[index][1])
  select index;
```

The basic idea is to iterate over the indices in order to make sure that you're comparing the appropriate rows and list items to one another. Once you do that, it's simple enough to parse the list item and make the appropriate comparisons.